# Android button border stay deafault after adding drawable file

Tags: android, xml, button, border

I'm working on a project in android studio and I'm trying to change the border to my button.
My default button when I just add it to my grid  look like this:

[image]

After adding new XML file (called box_solid_border.XML) in the drawable file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <stroke
        android:width="4dp"
        android:color="#000000" />

</shape>
```

the result is that it's creating the next shape that I can see:

[image]

**and that exactly what I want to add to my button.**

when I come back to my XML at the main file and add to my button the next line:

[image]

as  you can see in line 226 I'm adding the background that I just created for this button to the button. and near the line, there is the exact border that I want.
but in the application, the button still stays the same as the default one with no border added to him.
Like this:

[image]

Does someone know the reason that the drawable file doesn't affect the button?
If I'm doing the same thing for a textView or something else its works perfectly fine, just the button looks like not affected by the drawable extension to him.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add this attribute to your button:

```
app:backgroundTint="@null"
```

If it has both attributes `android:background` and `app:backgroundTint`(if you are using the default theme for your application, it has a default value), the color specified by `app:backgroundTint` will be cover on the shape of drawable.

Answer (score 0):

For border to button try to edit box_solid_border.xml in drawable folder
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`
`<shape`
`xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">`
`<stroke`
`android:color="@color/black"`
`android:width="5dp"/>`
`<corners`
`android:radius="8dp"/>`
`<solid`
`android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>`
`</shape>`

In layout xml file
`<Button`
`android:layout_width="match_parent"`
`android:layout_height="wrap_content"`
`android:background="@drawable/box_solid_border"`
`android:text="Button"`
`android:textColor="#fff"`
`android:textSize="30sp" />`